# Hibernate over JPA configurtation xml file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I know it's possible to configure Hibernate in the 2 following ways:

1. hibernate.cfg.xml
2. persistence.xml - JPA - with specific hibenate configuration
   when you add the provider like this:

   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

But , I don't understand when should I use which ?
What should be the correct behavior?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hibernate.cfg.xml when you want to use Hibernate in your project. When you create different queries (SELECT, INSERT, etc) you open session.

```
Session session = sessions.openSession();
```

where session is instance of **org.hibernate.Session**.
But as you can see we need sessions for creating session. Sessions is instance of org.hibernate.SessionSessionFactory. SessionFactory is global factory for concrete DB.
Session can be got by this action:

```
SessionFactory sessions = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

where `new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()` - parses **hibernate.cfg.xml**

**Persistence.xml** contains settings for using JPA in your project. Persistence units are defined in a **persistence.xml** file, which has to be located in the META-INF directory in the classpath. One **persistence.xml** file can include definitions for one or more persistence units. The portable way to instantiate an `EntityManagerFactory` in JPA (as explained in the JPA Overview section) requires a persistence unit.

See also: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit